# How to descend rows in laravel excel is like pressing control enter

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

[image]

In the code how can I give a new line down. I want to have days on a row and have to load every day.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/309)! for solution.

Set your value, with your tab "\r" or "\r\n" then

```
$sheet->getStyle('C1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

OR

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;

class InvoicesExport implements WithStyles
{
    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        $sheet->getStyle('B2')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: $sheet Which function is placed in?

Comment: I have modified answer. Please check. Hope it will help you.

Comment: it does have a new row, but creates 1 new rows.
I want it on a row but in text. Like the dark image above

Comment: `$data = [ "time" => "2020 \r 1996"]` but not dow line it does not create new rows, it creates 1 new rows

Comment: Are you using laravel excel package ? or core php ?

Comment: i use laravel-excel.com

Comment: Please refer answer. You have to map every row

Answer (score 0):

Just like...

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;

class ExampleExport implements WithMapping
{    
    public function map($row): array
    {
        $row = [];
        $dates = explode("", $row->dates);
        if(count($dates)){
            $row = [
                "col1",
                "col2",
                "date",
            ]
            foreach($dates as $d){
                $row[] = [
                    '',
                    '',
                    $d
                ];
            }
        } else {
            $row = [
                "col1",
                "col2",
                "date",
            ]
        }
        return $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer I need
I just want the same as when editing, press control + enter it will descend in 1 row
And this code will create 1 row with date and 1 row with enough col1, col2, date